# Custom Laravel Artisan Make Controller command

Tags: laravel, customization, laravel-artisan

I want to put my controller generated by the artisan command to a custom directory. I made own command

`php artisan make:command ApiControllerMake`

and extended it

`class ApiControllerMake extends ControllerMakeCommand`

then I removed everything from there and overridden method

```
protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
    {
        return $rootNamespace.'\Http\AppAPI\Controllers';
    }
```

It's working OK.
Then I overridden

`protected $signature = 'make:api-controller';`

and after run

`php artisan make:api-controller MyNewController`

I got error

`No arguments expected for "make:api-controller" command, got "MyNewController".`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `ControllerMakeCommand`, they use

```
protected $name = 'make:controller';
```

You probably have this:

```
protected $signature = 'make:api-controller';
```

So in your new class, replace `$signature` with `$name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was a little heavy-headed